# INSERT INTO Table and using uniqueid of Entry, INSERT into 2nd table, and using uniqueid of 2nd table finally a 3rd., each references the one prior

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Example; 3 Tables.

```
Table1 = Forms - (key) FormID int, FormName nvchar(30), Required bit, IsActive bit, IsDeleted bit
Table2 = FormLabel - (key) FormLabelId int, FormID int, LabelName nvhcar(30), IsActive bit, isDeleted bit, CustomeField nvchar(30), DisplayOrder int
Table3 = FormEntry - (key) EntryID int, FormID int, FormLabelID int, EntryName nvchar(max), IsActive bit, IsDeleted bit, DisplayOrder int
```

I need to create a Form, Then use that Form's FormID then be used as a Reference to Create a Label, and then using the created FormLabelId create X entries referencing both FormID + FormLabelId

There will likely be multiple FormEntry(s) to be inserted per Label per Form.

Example;

Create a new Form that with have 5 Labels, each with 5 Entries.
Form1 -> Label1 -> Entry1-5.
Form2 -> Label2 -> Entry1-5 etc.

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your looking for a nested relationship among three (3) tables: ***Forms, FormLabel and FormEntry***. Each one has a unique primary key and the relationship could be depicted as:

1. Forms is the parent entity.
2. FormLabel seeks **Label** registers from Forms table.
3. FormEntry checks registers from FormLabel table and, also from Forms table.

In  this way, a SQL script may be used with above mentioned entities as follows, supposing if you have a database called *MYAPP* in plain **SQL ANSI** already in a *SQL Server* on *Premise* or in a *SQL Azure* database engine:

```
    create Table Forms (
        FormID     int not null, 
        FormName   nvarchar(30), 
        IsRequired bit, 
        IsActive   bit, 
        IsDeleted  bit
        CONSTRAINT PK_FormID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FormID)
    ) on [PRIMARY];

    create Table FormLabel (
         FormLabelId    int not null, 
         FormID         int, 
         LabelName      nvarchar(30), 
         IsActive       bit, 
         isDeleted      bit, 
         CustomeField   nvarchar(30), 
         DisplayOrder   int,
         CONSTRAINT PK_FormLabelId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FormLabelId)
    ) on [PRIMARY];

    create Table FormEntry (
        EntryID         int not null, 
        FormID          int, 
        FormLabelID     int, 
        EntryName       nvarchar(max), 
        IsActive        bit, 
        IsDeleted       bit, 
        DisplayOrder    int
        CONSTRAINT PK_EntryID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EntryID)
    )  on [PRIMARY];
```

So, the [approach for Foreign Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15) on

> FormLabelId create *X* (*or n*) entries referencing both FormID + FormLabelId

that are you wrote could be generated with a set of Foreign Keys for FormID and for FormLabelId specified in the table FormEntry:

```
  /* FormEntry */
  alter table FormEntry
  add constraint fk_FormLabelID foreign key (FormLabelID)  
  references FormLabel (FormLabelId)

  constraint fk_FormEntry_FormID foreign key (FormID)  
  references Forms (FormID)   
  ;
```

This looks like:

[image]

However, in the example

> Create a new Form that with have 5 Labels, each with 5 Entries. Form1 -> Label1 -> Entry1-5. Form2 -> Label2 -> Entry1-5

You specify to create 5 Labels, thus, they're 5 registers on table FormLabel with 5 registers on FormEntry table, but no integrity rules are cleared here. The insight is used as follows with the same script with a light modification:

```
 /* FormLabel */
 alter table FormLabel
  add constraint fk_FormID foreign key (FormID)  
  references Forms (FormID) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ;
```

Where the keyword **CASCADE** is corresponding rows are updated in the referencing table (in this case, FormLabel) when that row is updated in the parent table (Forms).

So, I hope for your feedback is this worth.